# Can't find spark-hbase mvn dependency

Tags: maven, apache-spark, sbt, hbase

I want to read table in HBase using Spark. I added the following dependency:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" %% "hbase-spark" % "2.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

as mentioned in hbase [website](http://hbase.apache.org/hbase-spark/dependency-info.html), but the dependency can't be resolved !!

I also tried different versions (1.2.0, 1.1.2) and it didn't work.

Comment: Define "it didn't work"? Did you get any errors or your code is not doing the expected?

Comment: the depedency can't be resolved, I will edit the question

Comment: But if you want to use maven, why are you trying to add an SBT dependency? Shouldn't you be using a pom.xml file?

Comment: I also tried this dependency in pom.xml file and it can't be resolved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't look like `hbase-spark` is in maven central, which is the default repository that dependencies will be retrieved from.

You'll need to configure your build management tool (unclear if you're using Maven or SBT) to use the correct repository.

From the [project page](http://hbase.apache.org/hbase-spark/distribution-management.html) you can use

- https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots for
  snapshots
- https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases for releases

Currently, however, it looks like only snapshots are available.

Additionally, as mentioned in the comment from the author below, the line

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" %% "hbase-spark" % "2.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

should actually be

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-spark" % "2.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

The double % is not needed in this case as you do no want to append the scala version to the artifact name.

Comment: I'm using sbt. I tried to add these websites as repositories to my build.sbt. 
resolvers += "Spark-Hbase repo" at "https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
, but it didn't work also

Comment: hbase-spark does have a full set of artifacts uploaded, including jar,sources, javadocs.  You can view it here: https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/hbase/hbase-spark/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: This is weird, can't know why it is not working after I added the repository !!

Comment: It works now. I was using:"org.apache.hbase" %% "hbase-spark" as was mentioned in the website. but it worked with: "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-spark"

Comment: I've added that url for snapshot jars to the mvn settings.xml however it didn't help solving with problem. Actually question is how do we download those jars by using mvn?

Comment: does this dependency work with HBase version 1.1.2.2.5

Answer (score 1):

1. add this repository

   cloudera
               https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/
2. then u can download it by maven:

   org.apache.hbase
               hbase-spark
               1.2.0-cdh5.7.0

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue while using **hbase-spark** dependency in pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-spark -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
   <artifactId>hbase-spark</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0-alpha4</version>
</dependency>
```

I resolve the above issue by using following step:

- Download the **hbase-spark** dependency jar from [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-spark)  by click on the blue marking area as below image.

[image]

- Create a **lib** folder inside **/src/main/resources** as per the attached image.

[image]

- Copy the downloaded jar into **lib** folder and add the system path of jar file in pom.xml

.

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-spark -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
   <artifactId>hbase-spark</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0-alpha4</version>
   <scope>system</scope>
   <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/hbase-spark-2.0.0-alpha4.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Hope It will help you.