# not able to use org.apache.hbase 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT through maven

Tags: maven, apache-spark, hbase, snapshot

I am not able to fetch org.apache.hbase 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT using maven

these are my dependencies and repo prop :

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-common</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </dependency>

         <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-spark</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>apache-repo</id>
        <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

this gives : Missing artifact org.apache.hbase:hbase-*:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT

while https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots repo shows 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT for each of the above artifacts

how can i use org.apache.hbase 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT ?

Comment: I was able to download all above artifacts with version `3.0.0-SNAPSHOT` with your configuration. Can you please check your netwowk connectivity?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue while using **hbase-spark** dependency in pom.xml.

I have solved the issue by adding jar path in **System** scope in pom.xml as below.

```
<dependency>    
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>    
    <artifactId>hbase-spark</artifactId>    
    <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/hbase-spark-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

[Here is the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35698780/cant-find-spark-hbase-mvn-dependency/51153584#51153584)

Answer (score 0):

1. Set correct proxy:

```html
<proxy>
    <id>optional</id>
    <active>false</active>
    <protocol>http</protocol>
    <username></username>
    <password></password>
    <host>172.27.171.91</host>
    <port>8080</port>
</proxy>
```

2. just delete the last updated dependency files from maven folder and try updating maven.

Even, I tried and was able to download all above artifacts of version 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT with your configuration.